# Not-enabled 'use strict' is blocking execution of the code

Tags: javascript, use-strict

Yesterday, I was practicing just a real basics and everything worked fine. But when I opened test html today, I noticed that there are the error now:

> const otherDate = new Date();
>
> document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML
>   =`${otherDate.getDay()}/${otherDate.getMonth()}/${otherDate.getFullYear()}`;

This code printed actual date yesterday, now it shows 0/11/2018 (but console.log for new Date() is ok). I used debugger in browser and it showed me that the problem is that the 'use strict' is enabled and this code is in collision with it. But I have never activate it (I've read that some features or frameworks can enable it, but I didn't use anything, bootstrap, jquery, node.js etc. ... nothing).

Sorry for beginners question, maybe it's trivial, but I could not find the answer anywhere. Thank you for your help. :)

I am sorry, this error:

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be
>   accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls
>   to them at Function.remoteFunction

Comment: What is the actual error that you are getting? The one that you say: *showed me that the problem is that the 'use strict' is enabled and this code is in collision with it*

Comment: I think, you should add more context to the code excerpt. The error message contains a reference to some something called `remoteFunction`. Explaining the result: `getDay()` returns the day within the week (with 0 being sunday), `getMonth()` returns the month in the year, with `0` being January. Maybe you want to use `getDate()` and `getMonth()+1`? Maybe `Intl.DateTimeFormat` is relevant to you too. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: Thank you. As I said, even this short and non-contextual code worked, that's why I am so curious what happened. It was just an excercise so I am even glad it appeared, it's good for learning. Unfortunately I cannot find the reason for it. I am not experienced enough to understand `remoteFunction`, other that it has something to do with Ajax. Btw. thank you very much, @Hero Wanders, the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` is really great.